SQL FetchMany in the middle
So I'm fetching data from large tables. I'm using fetchmany to get 100,000 rows at a time. However, during my export, I will occasionally get a network disconnect, or need to stop the process for one reason or another.
I was wondering if there is a way to perform a fetchmany after a certain point. For instance, if I have a table with 1 Million rows. The program stopped in the middle and I can see I got the first 500,000 rows. Is there a way I can tell my fetchmany to start after row 500,000?
Edit: here's some code of what I'm doing. Moving data from one place to another.
curr.execute(
    '''
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM Database.dbo.Table_Name
    
    ;
    '''
    )
    progress = 0
    while True:
        rows = curr.fetchmany(ROWS_AT_ONCE)
        if not rows:
            break
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
        df_temp.to_sql(Table_Name, index=False, if_exists='append')


Please post your code.

I don't think there's any way to do this. You would need to modify the query so it returns data from the middle. E.g. in MySQL you can use OFFSET.

That will work @Barmar

If the query is ordered, you could specify the minimum value of the order field in the where clause.  For example, start with SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id, then when restarting SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id > last_id_that_we_retrieved ORDER BY id. This would avoid the performance hit that offset can introduce.

@snakecharmerb unfortunately I'm just trying to move tables and a good number of my tables have no autoincrementing unique column. The ones that do don't all call them the same thing. I actually have too old a version for offset. So I'm still kind of stuck on this. I ended up just running the whole thing again. It happens often enough to be annoying but not often enough that it stops what I need to do.

@David54321, can you elaborate '...just trying to move tables...' , there may be alternative methods once we understand what you are actually trying to achieve and not focusing (as is at present) on how to code 'it' , tks
